PowerShell JSON file to sorted array in single statement not working
In PowerShell 5.1, I am reading a JSON file into an array of objects and sorting them descending order by one property, but when I use a single statement, the sort does not save to the final variable. Breaking it into two statements works and I am curious why one works while the other doesn't.
Here is my code:
WORKS:
$versions = Get-Content $jsonFilePath | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$versions = $versions | Sort-Object -Descending -Property Version

NO WORKIE:
$versions = Get-Content $jsonFilePath | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json | Sort-Object -Descending -Property Version

EDIT...
JSON:
(already sorted in the file, but let's not assume that)
[
    {
        "UIVersion":  "2024.21.5",
        "Version":  "12.5.1.1"
    },
    {
        "UIVersion":  "2024.20.15",
        "Version":  "12.5.1"
    },
    {
        "UIVersion":  "2024.20.10",
        "Version":  "12.5"
    },
    {
        "UIVersion":  "2024.20.9",
        "Version":  "12.3.6"
    },
    {
        "UIVersion":  "2024.20.7",
        "Version":  "12.3.6"
    },
    {
        "UIVersion":  "2024.20.1",
        "Version":  "12.3.6"
    },
    {
        "UIVersion":  "2024.20.6.2",
        "Version":  "12.3.6"
    },
    {
        "UIVersion":  "2024.20.100",
        "Version":  "12.3.6"
    },
    {
        "UIVersion":  "2024.20.200",
        "Version":  "12.3.6"
    },
    {
        "UIVersion":  "2024.20.9.1",
        "Version":  "12.3.6"
    },
    {
        "UIVersion":  "2024.26.3.1",
        "Version":  "12.3.6"
    }
]


Please provide a sample of your Json

The reason why both examples don't provide the exact same output is very specific to ConvertFrom-Json in Windows PowerShell 5.1 and the reason is that the cmdlet outputs without enumerating each object. This is no longer the case for newer versions of PowerShell 7+ where the -NoEnumerate switch was added when there is a need to not enumerate the output (output the array of object as-is).
To overcome this behavior what you can do is wrap the expression in parentheses to force enumeration from pipeline. See Grouping operator ( ) for more details.
(Get-Content $jsonFilePath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json) | Sort-Object Version -Descending


That worked, thank you. I suspected that Out-String was unnecessary. Perhaps I copied from it from someone else. After reading about the new -NoEnumerate switch, I thought that no enumeration would be required for the pipelined sort to work. Can you help me understand why having the entire array (no enumeration) breaks the pipelined sort, whereas having is one element at a time (enumeration) makes it work? Or am I understanding enumeration incorrectly?

Out-String is not needed yes, if you want to read the file a single string always use -Raw. As for -NoEnumerate and it being required, it's the contrary, Sort-Object will look at the property value you give as argument -Property however if there is no enumeration, what Sort-Object receives is not "each object", but a single array containing all objects and the cmdlet is not designed to sort a single array from pipeline. It's designed to take each object from pipeline, collect them and then sort them. @Craig

If you want to dig deeper, what happened behind the scenes is that they were using by default WriteObject(theParsedJson, enumerateCollection: false) in PowerShell 5.1. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writeobject?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0#system-management-automation-cmdlet-writeobject(system-object-system-boolean) for details.

I saw -Raw, yes. And thank you for the explanation.
